# Upgrade purchase licences to iap purchases

Tags: c#, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

I want to change my active Windows Store application from a App with trial version with purchase option (after trial ended) to a free version with in-app purchase (to the full version). I want to give the users that have already bought the app the in-app purchase for free. How can i do that?

Answer (score -1):

To implement the in-app purchases in a desktop bridge app, you should use the Windows.Services.Store namespace . If you want to validate whether a given customer has purchased the product, you can use the [query for products](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/query-for-products) method in the [Microsoft Store collection REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service). The return data for this method confirms whether the specified customer has an entitlement for a given product, and provides data for the transaction in which the user acquired the product. (Derive from document: [Receipts for in-app purchases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#receipts-for-in-app-purchases))

Steps:

1.[Configure a Web application in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-1-configure-an-application-in-azure-ad).

2.[Associate your Azure AD client ID with your application in the Windows Dev Center dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-2-associate-your-azure-ad-application-id-with-your-client-app-in-partner-center).

3.In your service, [create Azure AD access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-3-create-azure-ad-access-tokens) that represent your publisher identity.

4.In client-side code in your Windows app, [create a Windows Store ID key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-4-create-a-microsoft-store-id-key) that represents the identity of the current user, and pass the Windows Store ID key back to your service.

5.After you have the required Azure AD access token and Windows Store ID key, [call the Windows Store collection API or purchase API from your service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-5-call-the-microsoft-store-collection-api-or-purchase-api-from-your-service).

6.Use the parameters(skuType,startDate..) to analyze whether the user has purchased your app before.